# Fast and easy image processing on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, effect

I need to do some image processing in an app I am developing. I have an ImageView and I need to set certain filters or effects to it (sepia, gaussian blur, greyscale, contrast, etc.). There doesn't seem to be any libraries (that I can find ;)) to facilitate this process. Android's EffectFactory only works on SurfaceViews. I found a [website](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/) with some tutorials but the performance is terrible, it takes a very long time to process the image.
Is there any not so difficult and fast way to apply the kinds of effects I am trying to achieve?

Comment: There are a number of image filtering libraries for Android on github. Have you had a chance to try out any of them?

Comment: Yes I have checked them out and tried many of them. My problems, as stated before, is that it they all seem rather slow. Some simple effects like greyscale take only a few seconds but gaussian blur takes upwards a minute to process. I look at the instagram app and it takes no time at all to process.

Comment: If you used something like android-gpuimage https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage which uses OpenGL shaders and still find it slow, then open a question on that specifically. Note that Instagram may be precaching results and/or showing a OpenGL texture rather than a bitmap as moving data in and out of the GPU is expensive.